# How can I detect that input is being redirected in from a file?

Tags: c++, redirect, input

I've written a program that takes its first argument and reverses the letters. So, for instance:

```
revstr cat
```

Will produce `tac`.

Now I want this to work when a file is redirected in. So, if *filler.txt* is a file containing "Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their country!", then:

```
revstr < filler.txt
```

Should produce:

```
!yrtnuoc rieht fo dia eht ot emoc ot nem doog lla rof emit eht si woN
```

But I don't know how to detect that such redirection is occurring!

This is what I've tried - obviously, it's no good. Where am I going wrong?

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
string temp,input,output;//store input from file, and get which file//

ofstream out("output.txt");

if(argc == 3)
{
    if(ifstream(argv[2]))
    {
        input = argv[2];
        ifstream in(input);
        while(in.good())
        {
            in >> temp;
            ReverseWord(temp);
            cout << temp << endl;
            out << temp << endl;
        }
    }
    else
        ReverseWord(argv[2]);


    }
    else
}
```

I'm fairly new to C++ and am doing my best to learn.

Comment: Where are you stuck? Do you want to know how to test whether the file exists?

Comment: Be aware of `std::reverse`.

Comment: @chris I assume this is a starter task to get into programming. nothing to learn, if you just use `<algorithm>`. ;)

Comment: Well the user types in "revstr < (name here or word)" straight into the console

Comment: @Mario, Probably, but if continuing on, it's good to know what's out there.

Comment: @MagicalToast, I think you just want them to type `revstr < filename.txt` or `revstr someword`. The latter would be passed as a command line argument, which you can check for and read input normally if none are given.

Comment: @MagicalToast We understood this. The question is, where do you need help with? Because writing `revstr < something` requires `something` to exist as a file or valid device.

Comment: @Mario For one, I'm not sure if I need to have the main function take in some parameters or not. I know I can Ifstream to check if it exists.

Comment: That really depends. If you pass `< somefile` as parameters, the operating system will read the file and not pass any parameters at all. One of the reasons chris mentioned the two possibilities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change your definition of your `main()` function so that it accepts arguments passed from command line:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
```

The first variable will hold the number of command-line arguments provided, the second is a vector whose elements are pointers to NULL-terminated strings. These strings are the command-line arguments themselves. Please keep in mind, that the first string will always be the name of the executable.

For instance, supposing the name of the file to be opened will be passed as the first argument:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::string filename;
    if (argc > 1)
    {
        // Oh, there's some command line arguments here...
        filename = argv[0];
    }

    // Go on processing...
}
```

Comment: Does the main function automatically count the arguments and put each into a section of the array?

Comment: Well, it's not the main itself function who does that, but yes, you can assume that when `main()` is entered, everything is set up already. Just remember that the first entry of the array is the name of the executable, so `argc` will always be greater than 0. The first command-line argument (if any is present) will have index 1.

Comment: I thank you for that I get that. I could test if the 3rd argument (since that is where the file name would be) and test it it exists. If it does I would open and take from it's contents, and if the 3rd argument is a word. It would test and see the file does not exist and then just continue.

Comment: @MagicalToast: Exactly. Good luck! :-)

Comment: I'm getting a weird error. My function takes in a string. so let's say the user enters "revstr < Tailor" because it is not a file It still needs to reverse the word Tailor, is there a way to fix this?

Comment: @MagicalToast: not sure I understand. Fix what? Reverse the string?

Comment: I have edited my code above. It can't take the word because it thinks it's a char?

Comment: @MagicalToast: OK, maybe I understand. Normally you would have one argument specifying the kind of processing the program has to perform, and then another argument whose meaning depends on the first argument. Take for instance `revstr -f filename` or `revstr -s string`. If the first argument is `-f`, then the following argument is a file name whose content shall be inverted. If the first argument is `-s`, then the following argument is a string that should be inverted directly. Btw, if my answer helped you a bit, please consider upvoting it :-)

Comment: I would if I could but I has no rep

Comment: I don't understand what command line arguments have to do with piping?  My understanding is that the OS pipes the output from one process to the standard input of another process.  So to read piped input, just use `cin`.

Answer (score 4):

There are two possible approaches for you (well, you can even support both):

1. You can accept a file name as command line argument (using a main that accepts arguments), then open an ifstream using this filename as the stream to read from. Users use your program like `revstr filename.txt`.
2. You can read your input from std::cin. Then users need to use redirection to pass you the contents of a file. If your program is started using: `revstr < filename.txt`, then reading from std::cin will read the **contents** of the file. The program never even sees the filename.

You can support both by reading from an ifstream, if you get an argument, and from cin, if you don't get an argument. The function that does the reading can get the steam passed in as a generic istream&.

Comment: Hi there. short and great answer. but can you answer my question regarding to this too ?

Consider _less_ command. we all know that you can direct to it's input like this: _ls -la | less_
but when you try to execute _less_ without any parameters, you get an error that you need a file as argument.

**How can you implement this programmatically ?**